# "can be clearly seen" OR "can clearly be seen"

Tags: differences, word-order, adverb-position

In my essay the sentence

> The results can **be** clearly seen.

was corrected to:

> The results can clearly **be** seen.

What is the rule behind this correction?

Most of the time I use **"can be"** together without any words in between. Is that wrong?

Comment: They mean different things. Use whichever version is relevant. #1 see clearly; #2 it is obvious that there are results. Admittedly, #2 can be parsed to mean #1.

Comment: Would you elaborate? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Clearly" is ambiguous between interpretations as a manner adverb ("in a clear manner") or as a sentence adverb ("it is clearly the case that ...").  In your first example ("The results can be clearly seen"), in my opinion, the preferred interpretation is as a manner adverb, but the interpretation as a sentence adverb is also possible.

For the second example ("The results can be seen clearly"), with primary stress on "clearly", the interpretation is that of a manner adverb.  However, with primary stress on "seen", it's a sentence adverb.

In sentence initial position ("Clearly, the results can be seen"), it's a sentence adverb, and also when the adverb comes after the subject ("The results clearly can be seen"). It's also a sentence adverb when it comes after the modal "can".